# Request document Identification (Ancient Scroll?)

Tags: hebrew, aramaic, text, pictures

Hi I have a document from Tunsia that I can't identify.  Can anyone help me with this?[image: Unknown Scroll]

Comment: Thanks.  I've [edit]ed that into your question.  If you know anything else (suspected timefrmae, collection where it was found (a geniza? somebody's attic? a museum?), etc, please add it.  Also, welcome to Mi Yodeya!

Comment: Unfortunately, there is nothing more to it I can add.

Comment: It looks like it might be written in some form of [Judeo-Arabic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judeo-Arabic_languages), which would make sense if it's from [Tunisia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judeo-Tunisian_Arabic), as you say. But it's a little bit unintelligible to the untrained (or inadequately trained) eye.

Comment: ..I'm wondering what it's illustrating... looks like it might possibly be Elisha making the poisoned stew edible, maybe?

Comment: Definitely looks like Judeo-Arabic.

Comment: The art style resembles later-middle-ages Europe, but the colors are unusual for (what survives from) that period.  Could be a later work imitating an earlier style, of course.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain but it appears to be some kind of blank agreement with the year not written in on the first line. The first line reads something like this, "With great blessing, sealed on the XXth of Shevat,(blank for year)". It is definitely Jewish from the symbolism and script but is too short to be any kind of ketubah. It is possible that this is some kind of "Tannaim", a document of betrothal or intent to marry. The holy name written at the bottom is usually associated with blessings for procreation and marriage like is found in Sefer Raziel HaMalach.